# ¿Como agregar titulo a recyclerview de acuerdo a lista?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json

He generado una lista con recyclerview pero no encuentro  un link o método para agregar el "header" o la sección donde van los nombres de los datos. Solo tengo la lista y el tab de la actividad pero no encuentro manera de indicar que valores estoy mostrando en la lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy haciendo es extraer los datos desde una url en json y la convierto en un objeto para luego añadirlo en una lista para recyclerview, pero no puedo encontrar la manera de colocarle el nombre en la barra superior con su dato correspondiente.

Comment: El RecyclerView está pensado para mostrar items del mismo tipo, podés agregarles dinamismo pero es una complicación extra que agrega complejidad. Te recomiendo hacer un xml padre que contenga un layout a tu gusto con los títulos y justo debajo de éste el RecyclerView que solo contiene los items data del mismo tipo.

Comment: Si es que aun buscas la respuesta, existen métodos para que puedas colocar los headers, uno seria crearlo como textView, y colocarlo arriba de tu recycler configurar el texView con wrap_parent y un gravity_layout "center" si es que cargas las listas separadas, si tu recycler carga datos por columnas tendrias que crear un linear layout horizontal y manejar las mismas condiciones en base a las dimensiones de tus items de tu recycler... si aun solicitas la respuesta escribime a para que pueda facilitarte ejemplos de varios proyectos en los que uso ese método.